# Amateur Radio License classes in Central Iowa

Tags: united-states, license

I'm looking for an amateur radio license class in central Iowa, near Des Moines.  I've been unable to locate anything through web searches.

Comment: If you are looking for a class to learn about radio amateur licensing, the best bet is to find if there are any amateur radio clubs in your area.  You could check ARRL (at arrl.org) but I just googled "amateur radio clubs in central Iowa" and got several hits and the first one is: http://dmraa.com in Des Moines.

Answer (score 1):

The ARRL's [License Class Finder](http://www.arrl.org/find-an-amateur-radio-license-class) should be able to help you; it says that there's a class in Indianola starting on the 8th of February.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a class but my brother and I have had quite a lot of success with 
https://www.hamradiolicenseexam.com

He completed his Extra class exam a week or two ago and I'm at like 38% for my own Extra class exam.  You just spend some time every day hitting the multiple choice questions and for the times when you don't get it, you can click and get the text again. The machine doesn't care if you have to read the text 40 times. The machine tells you when you are ready for the exam and you can take a practice exam any time you like. It's cheap, too. :-)

I like doing them one at a time as it's easier for me to notice my own progress that way. After I did Technician, I started with General and Extra class at the same time but didn't like how slow it was going by. One at a time was a perfect cadence for me though. :-)